# What is the maximum energy a 3.3 V LiPo battery can have?

Tags: batteries, esp32

I am thinking of using an ESP32-CAM with external wifi antenna (to send a 500k bytes in a range of more than 100m) and a 3.3/3.7v LiPo battery which sould last about a month (744h).
Concerning the power I am planning to keep the ESP32-CAM in sleep mode almost in 80% of the time which means the whole module will consume about 60mA.
So a perfect battery should deliver about 45000 mAh but there is no such 3.3 V LiPo.

I guess I need to use multiple batteries in parallel but I need to know the maximum (mAh) a 3.3 V LiPo battery can deliver. I also guess that there are no 3.3 V batteries big enough, only 3.7 V batteries.
Plus is it easy to charge it with a dedicated charge station like a Bat-Safe LiPo charge station?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear what you are asking, since you can build as large as pack as you want, by combining multiple cells. So in theory there is no maximum, other than how big a battery you want to build. 45Ah equals to a small car battery, or a large motorcycle battery.

Comment: There are certainly cells of that capacity and more, I've just bought some 280Ah LFP cells.

Comment: It's unclear to me why you need a 1S LiPo (3,3V or 3,7V) battery. All you need is approximately 150Wh. Considering a voltage converter with 90% efficiency, a for example 6S LiPo with at least 7500mAh would be a solution a well.

Comment: There is no maximum. You might be thinking of what the maximum you can get in 18650 form factor would be?

Answer (score 1):

Your power needs to be reduced and supply greatly increased.  I suggest a truck battery , buck converter with disable and LDO for sleep mode.